# Can I add this format in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, sum, date-arithmetic

I have a columns called time_spent and it is like: hh:mm:ss. For example, 00:23:11, this means it is 23 minutes and 11 seconds. I wonder how I can add up a multiple of these. Say like 00:23:11 + 00:10:20 = 00:33:31. I am not sure how to directly do that in commands. I have tried convert and CAST, but they ended up failed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn your times to seconds using `time_to_sec()`, sum them, and then turn the result to a time using `sec_to_time()`.

As an example, the following query would compute the total `time_spent` over the whole table:

```
select sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(time_spent))) total_time_spent
from mytable
```

This will work even it your times are stored as string, since their format complies to MySQL format for the `time` datatype.

Note that MySQL `time` datatype can handle values between '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59' only. If your total time is greater than that, then you will not be able to convert it back to a `time`.

Comment: Tags got changed after answers where added. Lesson in putting the right tags on to start with has hopefully been learnt.

Answer (score 1):

Once you store dates in `DATE`, `TIME` and `DATETIME` formats there are a multitude of available [date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the function [`time()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
select time('00:23:11', '+00:10:20')
```

or just:

```
select time('00:23:11', '00:10:20')
```

Result:

```
00:33:31
```

If the sum may exceed 24 hours, for example when you want to add `'23:59:59'` to `'00:23:11'` then use this statement:

```
select 
  case 
    when strftime('%d', datetime('00:23:11', '23:59:59')) = '01' then time('00:23:11', '23:59:59')
    else (24 + time('00:23:11', '23:59:59')) || strftime(':%M:%S', time('00:23:11', '23:59:59')) 
  end
```

Or:

```
select 
 (24 * (strftime('%d', datetime('00:23:11', '23:59:59')) - 1) + time('00:23:11', '23:59:59')) || 
 strftime(':%M:%S', time('00:23:11', '23:59:59'))
```

Result:

```
24:23:10
```